# Error symbol log running GPU on google cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to use google cloud ml with GPU mode.

When I train BASIC_GPU mode, I have many error log.
But, It works training well.
I am not sure whether the learning was good working in GPU mode.

This is error log history.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frRIl.png)

This is the some part of print config.log_device_placement.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQeGh.png)

Also, I tried training complex_model_m_gpu mode.
I also have error log like BASIC_GPU.
But, I can't see gpu:/1, gpu:/2, gpu:/3 when i print config.log_device_placement. Only gpu:/0 i can see.

The important thing is that BASIC_GPU and complex_model_m_gpu have same speed for running time.

I wonder whether the learning was good working in GPU mode or there is something wrong.

Sorry for my english, anyone knows the problem then help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to TensorFlow's [performance guide for optimizing for GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu) for tips on how to make the most of your GPUs.

A couple things to note

- You can turn on logging of device placement to see which ops get assigned to which Devices. This is a great way to check that ops are actually assigned to GPUs and that you are using all GPUs when you have multiple GPUs.
- TensorBoard should also provide information about device placement so that is another way to check that you are using all GPUs.
- When using multiple GPUs, you need to make sure you are assigning ops to all GPUs. The [TensorFlow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu) provides more information on this topic.